# simscape motor speed is not stable system

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I'm trying to build dc motor in simscape

I used the command `ssc_dcmotor` to get the example

I added controlled voltage source instead of voltage source and s-ps converter and 
made input port ... i replaced scope with output port

I made this to get linear model of speed of dc motor using `[A, B, C, D]=linmod('dcmotor')`

When I get `eig(A)` I see poles at zero which means system is not stable

What is the bug in my understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of the system returned by `linmod` includes the states of all it's blocks (even if these states are empty or constant).  Try executing

```
sstr= linmod('dcmotor1');
disp(sstr.StateName);
```

and you will see

> ```
> [1x50 char]
> [1x50 char]
> 'dcmotor1/DC Motor/Inertia'
> 'dcmotor1/DC Motor/Rotor Inductance'
> 'dcmotor1/Sensing/Ideal Rotational Motion Sensor'
> 'dcmotor1/DC Motor/Friction'
> 'dcmotor1/DC Motor/Rotor Resistance'
> [1x50 char]
> [1x50 char]
> ```

Obviously, we don't need the states of `DC Motor/Friction`, `Rotor Resistance`, `Ideal Rotational Motion Sensor` and their equations of the form dx/dt= 0.
However, it is easy to remove the unused states (The Control System Toolbox is needed):

```
sys= ss(A,B,C,D);     % create the state space model
sys= minreal(sys)     % remove the unnecessary states
pole(sys)             % now we can calculate the poles
```

Comment: That is great and helpful, is it useful in simmechanics too?

Comment: @Ammar Atef Yes, it is